# App crash when execute asynctask in togglebutton click event

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm writing an app for my personal usage when it activate and deactivate my security camera. During the startup of my app, I will execute an URL (using asynctask) to check the status of the activation and update a text field, button text and image.
Then, I'll click the togglebutton in order to activate/deactivate it by executing different URL using the asynctask call and it crashed. 
I couldn't figure out what is reason for the crash.
Can you please advise?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvKitchenStat= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarmstatuskitchen);

    //Set togglebutton click event
    setKitchenButtonClickListener();

    //Execute URL to get status - Kitchen
    mKeyWord="KitchenCheckStat";
    new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://www.example.com");
}

//For Kitchen
private void setKitchenButtonClickListener(){
    Button toggleButtonKitchen = (Button)findViewById(R.id.toggleButtonKitchen);
    toggleButtonKitchen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                if (mKitchenIsActivated){
                    //Diarm it
                    mKeyWord="KitchenDisarm";
                    new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://www.example.com");

                }
                else{
                    //Arm it
                    mKeyWord="KitchenArm";
                    new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://www.example.com");
                }   
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("ButtonClick", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
 private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        return GET(urls[0]);
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        UpdateKitchenStat();

   }
}
```

Here is the log:

> 02-10 21:33:39.642: I/System.out(7199): AsyncTask #2 calls detatch()
>   02-10 21:34:30.992: W/dalvikvm(7199): threadid=14: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x417e7da0) 02-10 21:34:31.032:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(7199): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2 02-10
>   21:34:31.032: E/AndroidRuntime(7199): Process:
>   com.kcyeoh.android.cctvcontrol, PID: 7199 02-10 21:34:31.032:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(7199): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured
>   while executing doInBackground() 02-10 21:34:31.032:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(7199):   at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300) 02-10 21:34:31.032:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(7199):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>   02-10 21:34:31.032: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>   02-10 21:34:31.032: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242) 02-10
>   21:34:31.032: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 02-10
>   21:34:31.032: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   02-10 21:34:31.032: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   02-10 21:34:31.032: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 02-10 21:34:31.032:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(7199): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:
>   println needs a message 02-10 21:34:31.032: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):
>     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method) 02-10 21:34:31.032:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(7199):   at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:156) 02-10
>   21:34:31.032: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at
>   com.kcyeoh.android.cctvcontrol.MainActivity.GET(MainActivity.java:168)
>   02-10 21:34:31.032: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):   at
>   com.kcyeoh.android.cctvcontrol.MainActivity$HttpAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:136)
>   02-10 21:34:31.032: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):   at
>   com.kcyeoh.android.cctvcontrol.MainActivity$HttpAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
>   02-10 21:34:31.032: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):   at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) 02-10 21:34:31.032:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(7199):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 02-10
>   21:34:31.032: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     ... 4 more 02-10 21:36:09.022:
>   I/Process(7199): Sending signal. PID: 7199 SIG: 9

Here's the code for GET,

```
 public static String GET(String url){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {

        // create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // make GET request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

        // receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        // convert inputstream to string
        if(inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the logs of the crash.?

Comment: Hi Ranjith, i have updated with the logs. Thanks.

Comment: The error happens in a method called "GET". Can you post the code for that please? com.kcyeoh.android.cctvcontrol.MainActivity.GET(MainActivity.java:168) 02-10 21:34:31.032:

Comment: More specifically, at line 168 because of this `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message`

Comment: Hi Gil Moshayof, I have updated with GET code. Thanks.

Comment: I think Log.d causing issue. append a string to it and check!

Comment: make it like Log.d("InputStream","error"+ e.getLocalizedMessage());

Comment: Yup..thats right..thats my understanding too. Just remove e.getLocalizedMessage() and try.

Comment: i.e try `Log.d("InputStream", "my error here");` , we can find the root cause if this is causing the problme.